# How to revoke public permissions from a Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a Amazon S3 Bucket to store only images from my website. I have more than 1 million images all with public read access. Everytime I make a login, Amazon gives me this warning:

"*This bucket has public access
You have provided public access to this bucket. We highly recommend that you never grant any kind of public access to your S3 bucket.* "

I'm using the following Bucket Policy to only allow images to be shown just in my site:

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originated from www.example.com and example.com.br",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket.com/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://www.example.com/*",
                        "http://www.example.com.br/*",
                        "https://www.example.com/*",
                        "https://www.example.com.br/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I revoke the public access to the bucket and to my files and grant it only to my sites?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a scary warning meant to prevent people from leaking data unintentionally. There have been lots of cases in the news lately about companies accidentally setting permissions to allow public reads.

In your case you really do want these to be publicly readable so you can just ignore the warning. Your security policy looks fine and still matches the documentation for public hosting.

You could theoretically put these images behind another server that streams them to the user if you really don't want someone to be able to download them directly. That's not really any more secure though.

If you do not want to have these publicly available at all just delete this policy from your bucket. In that case your website will not be able to serve the images.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I deleted the policy and the images still working because I uploaded them with Public Read. But considering I have more than 1 million images it's impossible to change all permissions... Thank you!

Comment: @Andre this is why it's important to test not only whether your bucket policy allows what you expect, but also whether it denies what you don't expect.  With `public-read` on the objects, the policy above was not actually doing anything.  If you still want to deny by referer, you could create a `Deny` policy testing `StringNotLikeIfExists` the `aws:referer` condition key, but use caution because access from the console and other internal mechanisms may be denied if you don't provide the necessary match conditions to prevent this policy from denying them.

Answer (score 5):

Your policy looks good. You are providing a higher level of security then just public thru the referer header and not allowing the listing of objects.

Using S3 to provide common files such as CSS, JS and Images is just so easy. However, with all of the accidental security problems I usually recommend one of these approaches:

1. Turn on static web site hosting for the bucket. This makes it very clear to future admins that this bucket is intended for public files. Also I do not see big warning messages for these buckets. Enable redirect requests.
2. Better, turn off all public access and use CloudFront. Enable Origin Access Identity. You receive all the benefits of CloudFront, tighter security, etc.

[Using an Origin Access Identity to Restrict Access to Your Amazon S3 Content](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

Comment: Good suggestions.  Note the comment on another answer, the objects are also `public-read`, so the bucket policy as shown is currently kind of a no-op.  Also, to cleanly use referer filtering with CloudFront is a little bit messy, requiring either a Lambda@Edge Viewer Request trigger to inspect and deny or forwarding the Referer to the bucket, which is only available with static website endpoints, not REST (so no OAI), and the latter solution has a negative impact on cache hits if your assets are referenced by multiple referring pages.